# Is there a Grid View module/component usable in an electron App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gridview, electron

I'd like to render a floating editable grid view on an Electron App.
Is there any GUI module, or js/css framework or anything that can be used in an Electron App other than building it from scratch?

Comment: What have you tried to use? Why did it not work for you?

Comment: Nothing, that's why I'm asking. To know what to try.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/

Answer (score 2):

Since the view of an Electron app is rendered with Chromium, you can use any HTML / CSS functionality used on the web.

Probably the most used one: [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)